# Send buttons click values from activity to non activity

Tags: java, android

I want to  send button click string values from activity to non activity class I tried startActivity() and getIntent() functions but it didn't work I also made public class in non activity class in order to initialize onCreate function to get button click. 
here is my Activity class of buttons initialization 
**MainSecond.java**

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_main);


    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(MainSecond.this,"b1c",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainSecond.this, SegmentBitmapsLoader.class);
            i.putExtra("message","hello");
            startActivity(i);




        }
    });

    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(MainSecond.this,"b2c",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent i2 = new Intent(MainSecond.this, SegmentBitmapsLoader.class);
            i2.putExtra("message","hi");
            startActivity(i2);

        }

    });
}
```

and this is my non activity function :

```
public class SegmentBitmapsLoader extends AbsAsyncDataLoader<List<SegmentBitmap>> {

private Uri mImageUri;

int r;

public SegmentBitmapsLoader(Context context, Uri imageUri) {
    super(context);

    mImageUri = imageUri;


}

public class segmentbitmapsloader extends Activity{
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

    if (message.equals("hello")) {
        r=1;

    }
    else if (message.equals("hi")) {

         r=0;
    }
}
```

}
}

Comment: I have to ask-  do you understand Java at all?  These should just be normal constructors and function calls, you would never use an Intent for this type of thing.

Comment: Sorry but I am new in android java,  what should I do

Answer (score 0):

I don’t quite understand your question. But, if you want to send data from one class to other, than you can use basic java functionality.

For your code,you can declare the string in the Main class.
And assign the string value. 
message= “hello”;// or any string

You don’t need Activity. It’s very basic. 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-create-objects-java/

In other class (SegmentBitmapsLoader), you can get the String message by creating the object and calling the string

```
public void someMethod(){
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();//assuming MainActivity is your java class
String test = mainActivity.message;

}
```

Comment: I just want to send button click with messages  (hi and hello ) to the SegmentBitmapsLoader function